# Single Table Inheritance or Type Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I am facing a design decision I cannot solve.  In the application a user will have the ability to create a campaign from a set of different campaign types available to them.

Originally, I implemented this by creating a Campaign and CampaignType model where a campaign has a campaign_type_id attribute to know which type of campaign it was.

I seeded the database with the possible CampaignType models.  This allows me to fetch all CampaignType's and display them as options to users when creating a Campaign.

I was looking to refactor because in this solution I am stuck using switch or if/else blocks to check what type a campaign is before performing logic (no subclasses).

The alternative is to get rid of CampaignType table and use a simple type attribute on the Campaign model. This allows me to create Subclasses of Campaign and get rid of the switch and if/else blocks.

The problem with this approach is I still need to be able to list all available campaign types to my users.  This means I need to iterate Campaign.subclasses to get the classes.  This works except it also means I need to add a bunch of attributes to each subclass as methods for displaying in UI.

Original

```
CampaignType.create! :fa_icon => "fa-line-chart", :avatar=> "spend.png", :name => "Spend Based", :short_description => "Spend X Get Y"
```

In STI

```
class SpendBasedCampaign < Campaign

  def name
    "Spend Based"
  end

  def fa_icon
    "fa-line-chart"
  end

  def avatar
    "spend.png"
  end 

end
```

Neither way feels right to me.  What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Hi John.  Please post the code that feels ugly to you with the STI approach.  Where you iterate over subclasses, perhaps?

Comment: Hey! It's the code I posted.  Having hardcoded attributes as method calls like that.. feels weird to do that.

Comment: Are these hard-coded values different for each subclass?  I assume Campaign inherits from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: Yes, each subclass has these attributes but they are different. Yes  Campaign would inherit from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: This seems perfectly reasonable to me.  I suppose if you wanted to, you could still store these values in the db using seeds, and then in an initializer, you could set class variables on the submodels.  Or just load them from a yaml file.

Comment: Did you consider using an [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A not very performant solution using *phantom methods*. This technique only works with Ruby >= 2.0, because since 2.0, unbound methods from modules can be bound to any object, while in earlier versions, any unbound method can only be bound to the objects `kind_of?` the class defining that method.

```
# app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :campaign_type => [:spend_based, ...]

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    campaign_type_module.instance_method(name).bind(self).call
  rescue NameError
    super
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_private=false)
    super || campaign_type_module.instance_methods(include_private).include?(name)
  end

  private
  def campaign_type_module
    Campaigns.const_get(campaign_type.camelize)
  end
end

# app/models/campaigns/spend_based.rb
module Campaigns
  module SpendBased
    def name
      "Spend Based"
    end

    def fa_icon
      "fa-line-chart"
    end

    def avatar
      "spend.png"
    end 
  end
end
```

### Update

Use *class macros* to improve performance, and keep your models as clean as possible by hiding nasty things to concerns and builder.

This is your model class:

```
# app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CampaignAttributes

  enum :campaign_type => [:spend_based, ...]
  campaign_attr :name, :fa_icon, :avatar, ...
end
```

And this is your campaign type definition:

```
# app/models/campaigns/spend_based.rb
Campaigns.build 'SpendBased' do
  name    'Spend Based'
  fa_icon 'fa-line-chart'
  avatar  'spend.png'
end
```

A concern providing `campaign_attr` to your model class:

```
# app/models/concerns/campaign_attributes.rb
module CampaignAttributes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    private
    def campaign_attr(*names)
      names.each do |name|
        class_eval <<-EOS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def #{name}
            Campaigns.const_get(campaign_type.camelize).instance_method(:#{name}).bind(self).call
          end
        EOS
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And finally, the module builder:

```
# app/models/campaigns/builder.rb
module Campaigns
  class Builder < BasicObject
    def initialize
      @mod = ::Module.new
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args)
      value = args.shift
      @mod.send(:define_method, name) { value }
    end

    def build(&block)
      instance_eval &block
      @mod
    end
  end  

  def self.build(module_name, &block)
    const_set module_name, Builder.new.build(&block)
  end
end
```